# Set token client side with Rest API in Symfony2

Tags: api, rest, symfony, curl, wsse

I made a Rest API with symfony2 on one server (S1).

I made an application with symfony2 on one server (S2).

**S1 :**
Works well. It gives json response of user's informations, depends of url given.

**S2 :**
Works well. Ask url with curl. Use wsse in the http header for retrieve important user's informations.

I want log in my users (from S2) using S1 database.
But when i am in S2, after the json response with user's informations, i don't know what i need to do and how do it...

Application side :
- Symfony2

API side :
- Symfony2
- FOSUserBundle
- FOSRestBundle
- JMS

It's the first time i try to make an Rest API, so maybe i don't understand well how it works.

Thank's in advance.

**EDIT :** For more details.

- 1 : User 1 use a log in form and send it.
- 2 : S2 Create a http header with x-wsse parameter (Nonce / Timestamp / Username / Password...)
- 3 : S2 send this header to S1 with curl
- 4 : S1 retrieve datas and if the header have good informations, send back the user's informations (in json) or make some actions
- 5 : S2 retrieve jsons informations of the user from S1.
- 6 : I can display the page like i want to the User 1

Now my problem is that i need to do the same thing for a new page, but i don't want ask my user for a password and a username a second time because for him, he is log in.

Hope it's more clear.

**EDIT 2 :** My problem resume in one sentence.

In Symfony2, with wsse authentication, how can i get a user's token and send it to client side after authentication on the API.

:p

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom authentication. Fortunately for you, this Symfony cookbok entry will show you how to do it with WSSE:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Comment: Yes, i already followed this doc for deploy the custom authentication on S1 server.
Like i said, the API make a good job, i retrieve json from api with authentication, but i don't know how i can set a token or something like that for don't have to ask the password of my users all the time on the application side. Maybe i don't do it good, i need to deploy a custom authentication on application side too ?

Answer (score 0):

Your S1 application returns a token when you authenticate from the S2 app, right ?

Then all you need to do is store this token somewhere in your S1 app (an entity, redis, ... Whatever), and when a foreign app (such as your S2 app)  ask for a resource while providing this request with a token, you just gotta check out if the token exists and is valid.

If it is, then you can authenticate the user on the S1 with Symfony's security component.

Comment: Hello. In fact S1 return a json response of user's data if the http header (send by a "client") is good (nonce + timestamp + digest...). So in S2, i just have json response not a token. After i make the client (S2) for ask the ressources but i don't know how manage the token. I read that the goal was to send a header request created with the password and username. An after, exchange a token. But i don't know excatly how do it...

Comment: Well, in fact it lies in one sentence (such as the summary of your question) : you need to generate a token, send it to S2, and ask S2 to send it each time (via a header, a query arg, ... the choice is yours). Then, on S1, for each request, you may check the validity of your token (does it exists ? Is it still valid ? Who does it belong to ?). That's the gist of an API. :)

Comment: Thank you. It was what i thought. But i expected at some code for help me because i block at this part. My authentication provider is created with the official doc of symfony and work well. But now i am in my controller and i need to response to the client and i don't know how generate the token and with what... 

http://pastebin.com/pHxMTitb

Comment: I'll try to edit my answer when I have some time to add some code then, but you got something in your paste, even though it should be on your S1.